# rosserial, multiple callbacks and interrptions?

Tags: ros, multiple, callback, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am new to rosserial.
The objective of this program is to make a LED (pin 13) blink with a Period=5s, and then exit this blinking.

Thus, after connecting ROS to Arduino via USB,  I apply a 'toggle_msg" to initiate the process (which runs perfectly), and my will is that the process ends when I apply a "end_msg" message. Each message has its own callback function as you can see.On the ROS terminal I apply each message this way:

```
rostopic pub toggle_led std_msgs/Empty --once

rostopic pub end_led std_msgs/Empty --once
```

The problem is that I do not know how to exit the while loop in the first callback, and the process really never ends. How can I do this?

The code is here:

```
# include <ros.h>
# include <std_msgs/Empty.h>
    
 int k=0;     
    
    
ros::NodeHandle  nh;

void messageCb( const std_msgs::Empty& toggle_msg){        

  while(k==0){

  digitalWrite(13, HIGH-digitalRead(13)); 

  delay(5000); 


}

}

void messageCb1( const std_msgs::Empty& end_msg){                 
k=1;
delay(1000);
}

ros::Subscriber<std_msgs::Empty> sub("toggle_led", &messageCb );   
ros::Subscriber<std_msgs::Empty> sub1("end_led", &messageCb1 );


void setup()
{ 
  
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  nh.initNode();
  nh.subscribe(sub);                                              
  nh.subscribe(sub1);
}

void loop()
{  
  nh.spinOnce();                                                    
  delay(1);
}
```

THANKS!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287043/rosserial,-multiple-callbacks-and-interrptions?/) by [blasrobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/34393/blasrobot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-03-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-29**:
Welcome! Can you please update your question with a copy and paste of your code using the *preformatted text* (`101010`) button? This will make the question self-contained and the link that you gave says that `.ino` files can't be previewed.

**Comment by [blasrobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/34393/blasrobot/) on 2018-03-29**:
Thanks, I added that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should not stay in the callbacks - just alter the values of variables to indicate what should happen in the main loop and work out whether it is time to toggle the led each time round if it is blinking

```
# include <ros.h>
# include <std_msgs/Empty.h>

int blinking = 0;
int ledState = 0;
long lastTime = 0;
long blinkInterval = 5000;

ros::NodeHandle  nh;

void messageCb(const std_msgs::Empty& toggle_msg){
  blinking = 1;
  lastTime = millis();
  ledState = 1;
}


void messageCb1(const std_msgs::Empty& end_msg){
  blinking = 0;
}

ros::Subscriber<std_msgs::Empty> sub("toggle_led", &messageCb);
ros::Subscriber<std_msgs::Empty> sub1("end_led", &messageCb1);


void setup(){
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  nh.initNode();
  nh.subscribe(sub);
  nh.subscribe(sub1);
}

void loop(){
  nh.spinOnce();

  if (blinking){
    long currentTime = millis();
    if (currentTime - lastTime >= blinkInterval){
      ledState = !ledState;
      lastTime = currentTime;
    }
  }else{
    ledState = 0;
  }
  digitalWrite(13, ledState);
}
```

---

Originally posted by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) with karma: 1504 on 2018-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0